# Configure default Apache website

Tags: apache-2.2, windows

I have recently done an IIS -> Apache web server migration and can't seem to work out how to access the default DocumentRoot externally. The server has several websites and using vhosts.

In IIS, you can create a "Default Website". I have this set to access my document root dir, for things like internal scripts etc and I could access this by the external IP; example document root is c:/www, i could access externally by `http://123.45.6.78/libraries/admin` (c:/www/libraries/admin).

How can I achieve a similar thing in Apache? I have many vhosts records:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/www/website1"
    ServerName www.website1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/www/website2"
    ServerName www.website2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine, but ServerName cannot accept an IP address. I hope I explained this OK.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this one out myself, kind of by accident.

Apache will look for a vhost record and fall back to the first one by default, so in the vhosts file at the very top I added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/www"
</VirtualHost>
```

I can now access it externally via the IP address.